# Jenkins updation and plugin installation

Tags: jenkins, java-8, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

This is how when I tried to list plugin via

```
println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)
```

looks like [list of plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcOYY.png)

I don't understand how is it displaying empty list.

Before All this what I was trying to do was fix my old jenkins because its installed plugins looked like this

[installed plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg7za.png)

I was using an older version of jenkins 2.190.x and I then updated it to 2.346.1 as my application is java 8 and saw its mostly the jenkins version which seems compatible with java 8. After I have updated, this error message remained and then I tried deleting some of plugins via the UI, and rest of them manually using command Line as I had trouble removing most of them via UI. After that, when I checked the installed plugins, it was all empty. Then I started installing from the basic plugins(which never really demanded an upgrade from my current jenkins version of 2.346.1).

But After All those installation, The same old error of "Some plugins could not be loaded due to unsatisfied dependencies." some how came back even though I haven't installed most of those plugins as you can see they required a higher jenkins version.

As I checked manually again, I saw this [plugin-list in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fbKl.png).

Now,My installed plugins section looks like how it was before installing the newer jenkins version. My terminal list of plugins looks like this. And when I use

```
println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)
```

its returning an empty list.

I guess I am missing something here, seems like I need to uninstall and reinstall jenkins and configure it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To view installed plugins use this: `https://URL_JENKINS.com/script`

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
```

Go to your Jenkins home directory and delete the plugins.txt file and the plugins directory.
Then restart Jenkins. It should download all plugins in the latest versions and their dependencies.

Please add information about how Jenkins is installed, standalone or using Docker or otherwise. It will be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks , I figured it out myself. I had lot of cyclic dependency issues and compatibilties that come with different versions. Got it solved by reinstalling manually with suitable versions and now with the script mentioned above, I am able view all the plugins and jenkins updation is done !